# Jmter beanshell sampler

Tags: java

i want to convert String variable into Date variable and vice versa in the same program. in the below code, DOB is String variable where date is stored and I want to get the Name of the  day in the week from any given date.

```
String dob_1= vars.get("p_dob");
String mnt_1 = vars.get("p_mnt");
String yer_1 = vars.get("p_yer");
String DOB = (dob_1 + " " + mnt_1 + " " + yer_1); //print the day from the 
obtained date(DOB).
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
String DOB = (dob_1 + " " + mnt_1 + " " + yer_1); 
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(DOB);
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
  try {
    return f.format(date);
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "";
  }
```